# Migration of website from http to https

Tags: javascript, css, codeigniter, http, https

I just moved my website from http to https.
The images, javascripts and css files have status 403 (Forbidden).
I am using php codeigniter.
What is it that I am missing?

Comment: probably you cannot request http resources from https webpage?

Comment: Many things can cause a URL to return a 403 error, none of them are directly related to using HTTPS.

Comment: Quentin: Could you please elaborate. ?

Comment: @Ameya — You haven't given us any information that could allow us to identify what the cause of the 403 errors is.

Comment: extending to my question, after I moved my website http://suggestionbox.tips to https://suggestionbox.tips , all websource files are forbidden 403, when I open a css file say https://suggestionbox.tips/application/assets/css/foundation/foundation.css it gives the same error. What could be the possibility. ? 
is there a mod_rewrite rule i need to change or httpd.conf file?

Comment: it has to do something with httpd.conf VirtualHost settings. http:// is working just https:// is not

Comment: can you please rename .htaccess in side application folder

Comment: did that, what should I expect.?

Answer (score -1):

add this to your .htaccess to move the entire website to https

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^example\.com [NC]
    RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
    RewriteRule ^(.*) https://example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
</IfModule>
```

Where `example.com` is your own domain. you can use your local ip or `localhost`

for localhost

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>    
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^localhost [NC]
    RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
    RewriteRule ^(.*) https://localhost/$1 [L,R=301]
</IfModule>
```

The above solutions work at the root of your domain. if you need folder wise

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On 
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^example\.com [NC]
    RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} folder 
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com/folder/$1 [R,L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: What type of webserver are you using? Can you check the **permissions** on your files? they should be `644` for files and `755` for directories

Comment: I have even tried giving 777 to entire folder did not work.

Comment: if its an apache setup, check if **www-data** (or any of your apache user) has the ownership

Comment: It has, still the same error. Man this is getting on nerves. Shooting in dark.

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of the file permissions? maybe also the owner data?

Comment: Well, strangely if it was permissions, I would not had seen the favicon at the top. is it not.?

Comment: Well i cannot see the favicon. You may be seeing the cached copies. 
http://imgur.com/Xz2s88O   http://imgur.com/8IN2YCd

Comment: Did you find an answer? @Ameya

Comment: Yes, I did. Just did everything again, right from ssl.conf to .htaccess. worked like charm. Not sure what the problem was at the first place.